# iOS: Segues vs IBAction?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am just starting to learn about iPhone development and there seems to be very little resources on using Story Boards.

I have two view controllers, ActionViewController and ActionDetailViewController. AVC list the actions that a user has committed whereas ADVC shows the details of that particular action.

AVC has a "+" button to add a new Action, while AVDC has a "Done" and "Cancel" button.

I really like using storyboards because they are a fantastic way to visualize the app. However, I find that using segues to transition between the two screens quickly becomes visually complicated. [image]

Can someone enlighten me what's the "typical" way of doing this? Do I really have a new segue for each action?

I also tried using IBActions. However, at AVDC I am unable to transit back to AVC with

[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Any ideas/

Comment: About IBActions, have you tried with `self.navigationController popViewController`?

Comment: Your honor, I'd like to present exhibit A in the case of Developers v. Storyboarding

Comment: Are storyboards not the recommended procedure for developing iOS apps?

Comment: Yes they are. They are designed to make the layout of Views View Controllers easier to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is set up a single Segue going from the AVC ViewController to the ADVC. Then when you want to perform the segue call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nameOfSegueIdentifier" sender:self];
```

Then override the delegate method below to set up the ADVC

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

Note you can use

```
[segue destinationViewController]
```

to get a pointer to the ADVC so you can manipulate it before it is pushed to the screen.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks I am actually familiar with this from the resources that i have. Still, do we encourage segues over IBActions in general?

Comment: I would prefer segues as it can be represented visually which makes it clearer what the app should be doing without having to search the code. It's not a big deal but even a tiny amount less friction in development is good :)